# ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.9

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, iis

Morning All

I am hosting my website on IIS , the website was built using the react template. But I have ran into a problem. When using localhost my webapp worked a charm, i could interact with the database and life was good. But now ive moved it over to IIS Im no longer able to pull data in from the database or interact with the db.

I think the problem may be the fact that IIS is running on a different server to my local machine. I have the ASP Core runtime installed on my local machine but not on the server where IIS is situated.

Can someone just confirm to me that I do require ASP Core runtime to be installed on the IIS server also?

Im not able to test things out until tomorrow otherwise I would find out for my self. Apologies, im basically a beginner with IIS and ASP

Thanks

Comment: What does "no longer able to pull data in from the database or interact with the db" mean? Are you getting any exceptions? Have you opened the firewall? Are you authenticating with the right user?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing troubles with the database connection and not with your API endpoints could be network/proxy/firewall stuff. But if you're not able to deploy your API to IIS maybe could be that you're missing the Net Core bundle. For more information check the link below:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.9-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are required to have the ASP.NET Core runtime installed if you plan on running asp.net-core applications on it.